# Facebook Messenger Bot - Image Attachment without compression

Tags: javascript, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger-bot

Is there any way to send an image attachment without compression?

I have tried "Upload Photos In HD" on Facebook App Setting but it doesn't work.

Comment: Don’t think so. And just because you think the images should be of better quality, won’t necessarily mean that users want their precious mobile traffic eaten up by that as well.

Comment: Yes, you are rigth. However, a Bot can be used also from a web version.